# Comparing Two Arrays and Grouping into Inserts and Updates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am comparing two arrays and then grouping them into inserts and updates. The updates array should end up including elements that match on `id == Id`, but where `open_balance !- DocumentAmount`. The inserts array should include only elements where the `id != Id`. Notice I am running both through the `toString()` method because in my scenario one is of type String whereas the other is of type Integer from two different SQL Databases.

Now, with the code I have now, the first grouping works - via the `findRecordsToUpdate()` function, I get all of the elements matched correctly for the updates - which should be two elements, because these two match on id, but not on the amount:

```
  recordsToUpdate: [
   { Id: '333', DocumentAmount: 20 },
   { Id: '444', DocumentAmount: 10 }
  ]
```

But the inserts, which is produced by the `findRecordsToInsert()` function, are not correct. According to my data I should end up with one element, with an Id of '555' in my `recordsToUpdate` array, because it's the only element with an Id not found in the other array -- i.e. it's a new record to insert. But instead I end up with 13 elements with my current code?

What am I missing here and what do I need to change to get the correct inserts populated to my recordsToInsert array?:

```
const sourceArr = [
  { id: 111, open_balance: 10 },
  { id: 222, open_balance: 20 },
  { id: 333, open_balance: 10 },
  { id: 444, open_balance: 20 },
]

const targetArr = [
  { Id: '111', DocumentAmount: 10 },
  { Id: '222', DocumentAmount: 20 },
  { Id: '333', DocumentAmount: 20 },
  { Id: '444', DocumentAmount: 10 },
  { Id: '555', DocumentAmount: 10 },
]

function findRecordsToUpdate () {
  if (sourceArr.length && targetArr.length) {
    let recordsToUpdate = [];
    for (let t of targetArr) {
      for (let s of sourceArr) {
        if ((t.Id.toString() == s.id.toString()) && (t.DocumentAmount != s.open_balance)) {
          recordsToUpdate.push(t);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('recordsToUpdate: ', recordsToUpdate);
    return recordsToUpdate;
  }
};

function findRecordsToInsert () {
  if (sourceArr.length && targetArr.length) {
    let recordsToInsert = [];
    for (let t of targetArr) {
      for (let s of sourceArr) {
        if (t.Id.toString() != s.id.toString()) {
          recordsToInsert.push(t);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('recordsToInsert: ', recordsToInsert);
    return recordsToInsert;
  }
};

findRecordsToUpdate();
findRecordsToInsert();
```

By the way, to clarify, my `findRecordsToInsert()` function should return a `recordsToInsert` array like this when done, as the record with an Id of 555 is the only record from the second array that doesn't exist in the first array:

```
recordsToInsert: [{ Id: '555', DocumentAmount: 10 }]
```

So, to be clear, it's just the `findRecordsToInsert()` function that is not working correctly at present.

Comment: do you have a result of it? btw, why do you not use same type for id?

Comment: Because in our real-world scenario the two are not the same type (I didn't set them up). I will add the result I want above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `Array#filter` and `Array#find` to get your insert and update arrays out of `targetArr`.

```js
'use strict';

const sourceArr = [
  { id: 111, open_balance: 10 },
  { id: 222, open_balance: 20 },
  { id: 333, open_balance: 10 },
  { id: 444, open_balance: 20 },
];

const targetArr = [
  { Id: '111', DocumentAmount: 10 },
  { Id: '222', DocumentAmount: 20 },
  { Id: '333', DocumentAmount: 20 },
  { Id: '444', DocumentAmount: 10 },
  { Id: '555', DocumentAmount: 10 },
];

// Target records with a matching source (on ID) where the amount has changed.
// Update these.
const recordsToUpdate = targetArr
  .filter(tar => sourceArr
    .find(source => source.id === Number(tar.Id) && source.open_balance !== tar.DocumentAmount));

console.log(recordsToUpdate);

// Target records that have no matching source record (i.e. new records).
// Insert these.
const recordsToInsert = targetArr
  .filter(tar => !sourceArr
    .find(source => source.id === Number(tar.Id)));

console.log(recordsToInsert);
```

**Edit**

Just for the record, in your original code the search in `findRecordsToInsert` is incorrect.  To fix the issue, try to find each target in source and, if not found, add target to the insert array.  But it's just a long-winded version of `filter`-`find`.

```js
const sourceArr = [
  { id: 111, open_balance: 10 },
  { id: 222, open_balance: 20 },
  { id: 333, open_balance: 10 },
  { id: 444, open_balance: 20 },
]

const targetArr = [
  { Id: '111', DocumentAmount: 10 },
  { Id: '222', DocumentAmount: 20 },
  { Id: '333', DocumentAmount: 20 },
  { Id: '444', DocumentAmount: 10 },
  { Id: '555', DocumentAmount: 10 },
]

function findRecordsToInsert () {
  if (sourceArr.length && targetArr.length) {
    const recordsToInsert = [];
    for (const t of targetArr) {
      let found = false;

      for (let i = 0; i < sourceArr.length && !found; ++i) {
        if (t.Id.toString() === sourceArr[i].id.toString())
          found = true;
      }

      if (!found)
        recordsToInsert.push(t);
    }

    console.log('recordsToInsert: ', recordsToInsert);
    return recordsToInsert;
  }
};

findRecordsToInsert();
```

Comment: That works perfectly, as is more succinct as well. Thanks, @avejidah!

Comment: You bet, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table and just filter the target array.

```js
const
    sourceArr = [{ id: 111, open_balance: 10 }, { id: 222, open_balance: 20 }, { id: 333, open_balance: 10 }, { id: 444, open_balance: 20 }],
    targetArr = [{ Id: '111', DocumentAmount: 10 }, { Id: '222', DocumentAmount: 20 }, { Id: '333', DocumentAmount: 20 }, { Id: '444', DocumentAmount: 10 }, { Id: '555', DocumentAmount: 10 }],
    source = sourceArr.reduce((r, { id, open_balance }) => (r[id] = open_balance, r), {}),
    recordsToUpdate = targetArr.filter(({ Id, DocumentAmount }) =>
        Id in source && source[Id] !== DocumentAmount),
    recordsToInsert = targetArr.filter(({ Id }) => !(Id in source));

console.log(recordsToUpdate);
console.log(recordsToInsert);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```